# Como deserializar data de Firebase con herencia en AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

Estoy haciendo una app muy simple para aprender a usar FireBase correctamente.

My problema viene cuando quiero deserializar objetos que heredan de X classe.

Ejemplo:

La clase AnimalManager sera la que contenga mi ArrayList

Las classes [Tigre.class, Perro.class and Gato.class] extienden de Animal

El problema es que FireBase no le importa la herencia y cuando deserializo mi clase AnimalManager.class **todos los objetos son animal** asi que los atributos especificos no son cargados los guarda como si todos fueran Animal. Eso quiere decir que ya no tengo ni perros ni gatos ni tigres simplemente animal.

Esa es la manera en la que supongo que FireBase funciona y guarda de esta manera:

[image: FireBase guardada ArrayList<Animal>]
Asi que despues de darme cuenta decidi cambiar la forma de hacerlo y usar:
HashMap Pensaba que ahora funciona! Pero ahora no tengo ni perros ni gatos ni Tigres. Todos son Object, asi que aunque ahora se guardan mejor tampoco me sirve:

[image: Serialized Animals HashMap<String,Object>]
My metodo init era de la siguiente manera:

```
   public void init(){
    this.animals.put("Gatos", new ArrayList<Object>());
    this.animals.put("Perros", new ArrayList<Object>());
    this.animals.put("Tigres", new ArrayList<Object>());
}
```

Asi que esto no funciona ya que son Object y no Gato, Perro o Tigre

Entonces decidí usar genericos:

```
public class AnimalManager implements Serializable {

private HashMap<String, ArrayList<? super Animal>> animals = new HashMap<>();

public AnimalManager() {
}

public void init(){
    this.animals.put("Gatos", new ArrayList<>());
    this.animals.put("Perros", new ArrayList<>());
    this.animals.put("Tigres", new ArrayList<>());
}

public HashMap<String, ArrayList<? super Animal>> getAnimals() {
    return animals;
}

public void setAnimals(HashMap<String, ArrayList<? super Animal>> animals) {
    this.animals = animals;
}

public void addAnimal(String key, Animal o){
    //this.animals.get(key).add(g);

    if(o instanceof Gato){
        Gato g = (Gato) o;
        this.animals.get(key).add(g);
    }else if(o instanceof Perro){
        Perro p = (Perro) o;
        this.animals.get(key).add(p);
    }else{
        Tigre t = (Tigre) o;
        this.animals.get(key).add(t);
    }
}
```

Pero entonces FireBase me lanza otro error!
**com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Generic wildcard types are not supported**

Asi que hay alguna manera de conseguir esto?
Quiero tener una ArrayList de Animales de mi aplicacion en un mismo array pero siempre teniendo en cuenta que son Gato, Perro o Tigre

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido estas en **SO en Español** traduce tu pregunta

Comment: Este foro es en espanñol por favor traducirla

Comment: Perdona soy nuevo pensaba que estaba en el ingles. Voy a editarla y ponerla en castellano.

Comment: Ya lo he traducido disculpad las molestas